# Populating TableView upon clicking action sheet Objective-C Prime No, value entered from textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

When I am importing the mutable array "primearray" from PRIME class and assigning it to nsmutablearray "array" declared in view controller it throws error.

Basically I am trying to populate the tableview with the contents of nsmutablearry.

The contents of this mutablearry declared in class depends upon the user pressing the button at index:0 in action sheet.

Can anyone help ??? Thanks in advance.

```
 IBOutlet UITextField *txt1;

    IBOutlet UITextField *txt2;

    NSMutableArray *arry;

    int startno;

    int endno;    
}

@property IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;

-(IBAction)ok:(id)sender;


@end
```

### END OF VIEWCONTROLLER.H FILE

```
 ViewController.m


    #import "ViewController.h"

    #import "PRIME.h"

    #import "NON-PRIME.h"

    #import "ODD.h"

    #import "EVEN.h"

   @interface ViewController ()

   @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a  nib.


   arry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



}

      - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
      {
          [textField resignFirstResponder]; 


          return YES;
      }

        -(IBAction)ok:(id)sender
  {
       // arry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


          startno=[txt1.text intValue];

         endno=[txt2.text intValue];

       if(startno ==0 || endno ==0 || startno > endno)
       {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"CHECK   INPUT "message:@"input must not be nil,zero or alphabet & endno must be  greater than startno" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL"  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

      }

 else

  {


  //if (startno !=0 || endno !=0 || !(startno > endno))
    {
      NSLog(@"1....start @%d, end @%d",startno,endno);

      UIActionSheet *action=[[UIActionSheet   alloc]initWithTitle:@"select your choice" delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel:" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"prime",@"non-prime",@"odd",@"even", nil];

       [action showInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

}

```
    - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet   clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

    if(buttonIndex==0)
{

    NSLog(@"2...start @%d, end @%d",startno,endno);

   PRIME *prime=[[PRIME alloc]init];

      [prime setnumbers1:startno sec:endno];

    [arry addObjectsFromArray:[prime primecal]];


    for(int i=0;i<arry.count;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"count : @%d",i);

    }
     for(count1 in arry)
     {

        NSLog(@" arry %@ ",count1);

    }
 }


if(buttonIndex==1)
{
    NON_PRIME *nonprimeobj=[[NON_PRIME alloc]init];
}
if(buttonIndex==2)
{
      ODD *oddobj=[[ODD alloc]init];

}
if(buttonIndex==3)
{

    EVEN *evenobj=[[EVEN alloc]init];

}
```

}

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return arry.count;
   }


      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)
        tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
          {

            UITableViewCell *cell;


        if(cell==nil)
           {

            cell=[[UITableViewCell    alloc]initWithStyle:
            UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"A"];

           }
       cell.textLabel.text=[arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       return cell;



  }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

   }  

   @end
```

### **end of view controller.m file**

```
 @interface PRIME : NSObject
    {

       int i,start,end;

       int remain,k,p;

       int count;

    //int count=0;   //error????

   }

    @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *primearray;

   -  (void)setnumbers1:(int)start1 sec:(int)end1;

    -(NSMutableArray *)primecal;
```

### END OF PRIME.H CLASS

```
     #import "PRIME.h"

      @implementation PRIME


     -(void)setnumbers1:(int)start1 sec:(int)end1
      {

       start=start1;

      end=end1;

  }



     -(NSMutableArray *)primecal
     {
        NSMutableArray *primearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

          for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
         {

           for(p=2;p<=1;p++)

        {
            remain=i%p;

            p++;
        }


        if(p==i)

        {
             [primearray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

            count++;
        }
    }

    return  primearray;
   }

@end
```

### END OF PRIME.M CLASS

Comment: @ReinierMelian in class  PRIME

Comment: check my answer I hope that can help you

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks for your help, its getting clearer now but how do I deal with calling the table view from action sheet clickedbuttonatindex method [index 0 is for Prime no generation]

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have declared the Tableview cellforrowatindexpath function.  But how do I call this function from if(buttonindex==0) . I would be thankful to you If you help me regarding this.

Comment: You only have to call your `[self.tableView reloadData]`, check my answer was updated

Comment: @ReinierMelian i'll inform you as soon i complete

Comment: OK, any doubt, let me know, as advice I can tell you that maybe you need to make your prime calculations on background thread, and updated later your table, because use of heavy methods on main thread can block your UI

Comment: @ReinierMelian it tells build succeeded but gets pause with showing breakpoint just below viewdidload, 

I thinks Xcode is indicating towards some issues related the declarations inside VIEWDIDLOAD

Also [self.tableView reloadData] inside action sheet is being shown as error

Comment: @ReinierMelian its not showing the desired output

Comment: What is showing?, errors on the calculation?

Comment: @ReinierMelian   self ViewController * 0x0718f5e0
prime PRIME * 0x0719ab00
arry NSMutableArray * 0x07191b50
endno int 0
startno int 0self ViewController * 0x0718f5e0
prime PRIME * 0x0719ab00
arry NSMutableArray * 0x07191b50
endno int 0
startno int 0

Comment: @ReinierMelian 
Thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 on the closing bracket of ViewController

Comment: Can you post your stackTrace of the error?

Comment: @ReinierMelian  self ViewController * 0x071d29e0

UIViewController UIViewController 

txt1 UITextField * 0x071da350

txt2 UITextField * 0x071e1660

arry NSMutableArray * 0x071d4f50

startno int 0

endno int 0

_tbl UITableView * 0x07bb1600

prime PRIME * 0x071ddf00

NSObject NSObject 

i int 1
start int 0
end int 0
remain int 0
k int 0
p int 2
count int 0
_primearray NSMutableArray * 0x00000000
arry NSMutableArray * 0x071d4f50
endno int 0
startno int 0

Comment: can you put your project repo on gitHub I will review and fix any problem and later, I tell you what you can do to fixit?

Comment: @ReinierMelian The whole code has been UPLOADED to   https://github.com/sk652438/repo_primeonprime

Comment: I will review and on Monday I will pull request my fixes, regards

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks  a lot

Comment: @ReinierMelian YOUR CODE WAS WHAT FINALLY LED TO MAKE SOME MAJOR CHANGES TOWARDS SOLVING THIS CODE, I HAVE RECTIFIED IT . THE MISSING PARTS HAVE BEEN ADDED YOU MAY GO THROUGH THEM.


   NSLog(@"arry.count @%d",arry.count);  /// //STILL not    working?????????

Comment: @ReinierMelian THE MAIN CODE ABOVE HAS ALSO BEEN MODIFIED ALSO BASED UPON YOUR SUGGESTIONS

Comment: check my fork is fixed already https://github.com/rmelian2014/repo_primeonprime

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank You very much

Comment: you can upvote my answer and accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you want to use a method from PRIME class but you are not initializing or using at all

I think that instead of

```
arry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

startno=[txt1.text intValue];

endno=[txt2.text intValue];

arry=[arry addObject: primearray]; //
```

you need something like this

```
NSMutableArray * arry = [NSMutableArray array];
startno=[txt1.text intValue];
endno=[txt2.text intValue];

PRIME * prime = [[PRIME alloc]init];
[prime setnumbers1:startno sec:endno];
[arry addObjectsFromArray:[prime primeCal]];
```

This is using your actionSheet

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet   clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
        startno=[txt1.text intValue];
        endno=[txt2.text intValue];

        PRIME * prime = [[PRIME alloc]init];
        [prime setnumbers1:startno sec:endno];
        [arry addObjectsFromArray:[prime primeCal]];
        [self.tableView reloadData]
    }

    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        NON_PRIME *nonprimeobj=[[NON_PRIME alloc]init];
    }
    if(buttonIndex==2)
    {
          ODD *oddobj=[[ODD alloc]init];

    }
    if(buttonIndex==3)
    {

        EVEN *evenobj=[[EVEN alloc]init];

    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Reiner Meilian Then how should i access the table view once user clicks on buttonatindex:0                                                    -(void)actionSheet: (UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
      
        
     }

Comment: You need to show the prime numbers after the user touch buttonIndex 0 of your actionSheet?

Comment: @kumar let me know if you finally achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

The only missing hat was preventing the output of the prime nos in      cells of normal tab;e view was as follow additions to the code :

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
 clickedButtonAtIndex:  (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

 [self.tbl reloadData];  //ADDED


}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView                    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  return arry.count;

  NSLog(@"arry.count @%d",arry.count);  /// //STILL not working????????? 
 }
```